# Tilt (Bundler dependency error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, slim-lang, tilt

I need to upgrade my apps to Rails 3.2.16, when I did `bundle update rails` it gives me the following error.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "tilt":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (= 3.2.6) ruby depends on
      tilt (~> 1.3) ruby

    slim (>= 0) ruby depends on
      tilt (2.0.0)
```

My Gemfile:

```
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.6'
gem 'slim'
```

I don't know how to fix this. Help please.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try explicitly adding 'tilt' to your Gemfile.

Comment: Did you specify an exact version?

Comment: Add this : `gem 'tilt', '~> 1.3.3'`

Answer (score 0):

I quickly tried bundle installing just those two gems and got the following dependency tree in my Gemfile.lock.

```
sass-rails (3.2.6)
  railties (~> 3.2.0)
  sass (>= 3.1.10)
  tilt (~> 1.3)
slim (2.0.2)
  temple (~> 0.6.6)
  tilt (>= 1.3.3, < 2.1)
```

as one of the comments suggested maybe try explicitly specifying the version of slim to 2.0.2 as it only requires tilt 1.3.3 or greater which is compatible with the version of tilt that sass-rails requires